# Why is CSLA named so?

Tags: csla

I read wikipedia entry and now going through Rockford's book. But could not arrive a straightforward answer to the meaning of name "Component based scalable and logical architecture".

I understand it helps developer design business objects loosely coupled to other concerns and support validations, n-level undo, parent child relation etc. But how can i related them with words Component, Scalabale, Logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework originated in the VB6 days. It was scalable and component based by those standards.

Comment: Rockford has since stated that CSLA is no longer an acronym, and the title of the framework is simply CSLA.   http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/7907/37743.aspx